# How to count values from the database table column?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I want to convert game tag data found [here](https://www.kaggle.com/nikdavis/steam-store-games?select=steamspy_tag_data.csv) into a dimension table of a star schema.

But the problem is that steamspy_tag_data table is organised as such every column name is tag name of a game and one game can have multiple tags. For example, lets say I have game Warcraft3 with appid 30 it would be in a table like this.

```
appid|strategy|action|shooter|fantasy|
-----+--------+------+-------+-------
30     6345    1452     0     6340
```

Column value greater than 0 signifies amount of user votes that voted certain game to be of that game tag. For Warcraft3 game with appid 30 - 6345 users voted it classifies as strategy 1452 users it classifies as action, .. etc.
Some columns for example "abstract" (column) tag has almost all 0 throughout the whole column meaning almost no game uses that tag, so to simplify 372 columns with over 29k row value into something more compact I want to run a query that would count non-zero value per every tag column and put them in the new table "tagovi" for better visibility which columns(tags) have relatively low game usage count.

so far I came up with this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `zbroji_tagove`()
BEGIN
DECLARE i INTEGER;
DECLARE total_row_count INTEGER;
DECLARE dummy VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE zbrojeno INTEGER;
DECLARE trenutna VARCHAR(255);

DECLARE kursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT column_name
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_schema = 'sppi' AND table_name = 'steamspy_tag_data'
  ORDER BY ordinal_position;

  SELECT FOUND_ROWS() into total_row_count;
  open kursor;
  FETCH kursor into dummy;

  SET i = 1;
ponavljanje: LOOP
    IF i > total_row_count THEN
    CLOSE kursor;
    LEAVE ponavljanje;
    END IF;

    FETCH kursor INTO trenutna;

    SET zbrojeno = 0;
    SET zbrojeno = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM steamspy_tag_data where trenutna <> 0);

    INSERT INTO tagovi(kategorija,broj_igra)
    VALUES (
                (trenutna),(zbrojeno)
);

    SET i = i + 1; 
end LOOP;

END
```

New table tagovi has 3 columns (ID auto_increment, kategorija Varchar(255), broj_igra INTEGER).

When I execute my stored procedure "zbroji_tagove"() I get SQL ERROR CODE 1292; Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value 'some_tag_name'. So somehow sql treats variable value as value instead of column at line SET zbrojeno = (*SELECT COUNT(*) FROM steamspy_tag_data where trenutna <> 0*);

Is there a way for me to accomplish what I want inside MySQL environment?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variables like that, you need a prepared statement

See

```
@sql = CONCAT("SELECT COUNT(*) INTO zbrojeno FROM steamspy_tag_data where ",trenutna," <> 0);";
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```